# Oracle SQL row counter with restarting incremental

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I would like to create a row counter with Oracle SQL. This row counter should start from 1 till 5 and then should restart again from 1.

Like:

```
ORDER, ROW_COUNTER
-----   -----------
ORDER1,1
ORDER2,2
ORDER3,3
ORDER4,4
ORDER5,5
ORDER6,1
ORDER7,2
ORDER8,3
ORDER9,4
ORDER10,5
ORDER11,1
ect...
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()` and arithmetics:

```
select 
    order_no, 
    1 + mod(row_number() over(order by order_no) - 1, 5) row_counter
from mytable
```

This assumes that the first column of the table can be used to order the records, although it would probably make more sense to have something more sensible than a string column (like an autoincremented column for example).

Side note: `order` is a SQL language keyword (as in: `order by`), hence not a good choice for a column name. I renamed it to `order_no` in the query.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, i used a dummy column name. But this is what i exactly wanted!

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies the ordering.

But the basic idea is to use `row_number()` or `rownum` and some arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       1 + mod(rownum - 1, 5)
from t;
```

Note:  The results from this are not *stable*; the table can be read in any order.